# Se que suena simple pero, me he liado un montón por esto. Bug de codigo

Tags: javascript

```js
let oneN = prompt("First number")
let twoN = prompt("Second number")
function iOne() {
    if (oneN >= twoN) {
        console.log(`${oneN} is greater ${twoN}`)
    } else {
        console.log(`${twoN} is greater than ${oneN}`)
    }
}
iOne()
```

Verás, cuando pongo este código y pones un ejemplo 110 como primero y 109 como segundo da el resultado de 110 es menos que 109, pero a la hora de poner un ejemplo, 50 primero y 100 después o al revés lo hace bien, cual es mi fallo? Estoy empezando con JS y todavía no entiendo muy bien la lógica.

Este otro si funciona:

```js
function greater(a, b) {
    if (a >= b) {
        console.log(`${a} is greater than ${b}`)
    }
    else {
        console.log(`${b} is greater than ${a}`)
    }
}
```

Queria saber que falla...

Comment: Estás seguro? Probando tu código se ve que todo fluye correctamente.

Comment: No, por eso pregunto, pero este otro si que me va bien, pero al ponerlo con alert, no me va, y queria saber porque:

function greater(a, b) {
    if (a >= b) {
        return console.log(`${a} is greater than ${b}`)
    }
    else {
        return console.log(`${b} is greater than ${a}`)
    }
}

Comment: El primero funciona perfecto.. probalo aca en la pagina...

Comment: De paso, si vas a usar la herramienta para agregar un fragmento js, agregalo en el cuadro que dice js, no en el que dice html.. asi se puede probar...

Comment: intenta borrar la caché de tu navegador, en ocasiones provoca falsos positivos, eso al menos en chrome

Comment: Podrías colocar una imagen o captura de tu problema. Eso ayuda, hay ocasiones que el navegador u otro ente interfiere en los resultados.